# popup window that passes values to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a popup window that has a form which contains inputs. there are 2 inputs and on submitting the form it should grab the values from the inputs and assign them to variables and then pass it to the php code. nothing i do seems to get the values assigned. Ive tried outputting the variables within the javascript but it just resets the text boxs when the button is clicked

```
   <?php
    include'../dbconnect.php';

    echo "in character creation";
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['type']) ) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];

        echo $name." ".$type;
    }

    ?>
    <html>
    <form id="frmNewChar">
    Character Name: <input type="text" id="charName"></input> <br />
    Character Type: <input type="text" id="charType" ></input> <br />
    <button id="btnNewChar" >Submit</button>
    </form>
    </html>

    <script language="JavaScript"><!--
    $("#btnNewChar").click(function(){
        var name = $("#charName").val;
        var type = $("#charType").val;
            $("#frmNewChar").before(name);
            // $.post(this, {name: name, type: type}, function(data){
                // text=data;
                        // elem = $("#frmNewChar");
                        delay=100;
                        // addTextByDelay(text,elem,delay);

                // });
    });
    //--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Jquery function should be like this,

```
$("#btnNewChar").click(function(){
        var name = $("#charName").val();
        var type = $("#charType").val();
            $("#frmNewChar").before(name);
            // $.post(this, {name: name, type: type}, function(data){
                // text=data;
                        // elem = $("#frmNewChar");
                        delay=100;
                        // addTextByDelay(text,elem,delay);

                // });
    });
```

You have used **val** instead of **val()**.